# iTunes always reset the "Automatically Back Up" option to "This Computer"

Tags: ios, itunes, icloud, data-synchronization

So, this section of iTunes idevice option always keeps resetting to "This Computer" from "iCloud", whenever the sync finishes / the device is reconnected.

[image]

Is there any guess why this is happening, even though iCloud Backup is turned on in my idevice's settings? Any solution I can try to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved - it seems that this error happens when you restore your idevice from icloud backup.

Go to idevice's settings>iCloud>Backup and disable and reenable iCloud Backup, and iTunes will now remember this settings.

tl;dr: it didn't have something to do with iTunes, the idevice was the problem.

Comment: Awesome, many thanks for this solution. I though I already did that, but this time I did it with the iDevice connected to my computer + iTunes launched with the "Automatically Back Up" options on screen. Disable and Re-Enable iCloud Backup on the iDevice automatically switched the options on iTunes. Now it will not always reset it to "This Computer".

Comment: I had the same problem except the other way around.  It kept resetting from "to my computer" to "iCloud".  Same fix:  Toggle the iCloud Backup option twice. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

So now one last thing ...if this one fails too ,,then its only Apple Support. 
Connect your iPad to iTunes. Back it up (check the Encrypted Backup box). 
When local iTunes backup is made, disconnect the iPad. 
Leave your iTunes app on   At your . 
Then with power on, at your iPad, make an iCloud backup. 
Check itunes app iCloud or iTunes (encrypted) backup is checked??
The (at all cases) sign out of iTunes account & resign in. 
Reboot  & iPad at the end of all the procedure. 
If those workarounds don’t work  ..contact Apple Support.

Answer (score 0):

Is yr Mac fully updated???
If not ... update all of your apps and your Mac OS too.  Then perform again the 1st post. Sign out of your iTunes account-sign back in again. 
Let me know how it goes. ‍

Comment: Yes, the preference on my both mac and iPad says everything is up to date. I also logged out from iTunes app store account and redo login but it still happens.